# How to wrap the content inside table cell without data loss and extension of the table width using iText 7 and Java

Tags: java, itext7

Table width goes beyond the right margin and some content inside table cell is lost when there is bigger word(continuous text) present.
[image: pdf.png]

Below code implemented to print table

```
public Table createTable(Document doc, UnitValue[] columnsWidth) {
    Table table = new Table(columnsWidth);
    table.setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.9f));
    float tableWidth = doc.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getWidth()-(doc.getLeftMargin()+doc.getRightMargin());
    table.setWidth(tableWidth);
    return table;
}

public void addTable(Document doc, AbstractElement<?> parent, Table table) {

    if(parent == null){
        table.setMarginTop(2f);
        doc.add(table);
    }
}
UnitValue percentageUnit = new UnitValue(2, 1.00f);
UnitValue[] percentageUnitArr = new UnitValue[2];
percentageUnitArr[0] = percentageUnit;
percentageUnitArr[] = percentageUnit;
Table table = createTable(doc, percentageUnitArr);
addTable(doc, iTextParent, table);
```

Comment: Wouldn’t a valid fix be to add a horizontal scroll bar? Much like with the vertical one you already have

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 Thanks for your quick response. No, I am not looking for a horizontal scroll bar as a fix.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but maybe try something by wrapping the text when it reaches the right edge of the box so it continues but just below. Also, you try adding a horizontal scroll bar to the cell itself when it goes out of bounds. Just some ideas

Comment: Oh sorry, that was the point of your question. I’m not too sure how to wrap the text with the code you’ve given, sorry about that.